# Question about the variations

Tags: calculus

Suppose x∝y                    or     y∝x
  than  x=ky                   and     y=kx
    consider y=2 and x=3
than   here
     k=3/2                 but here   k=2/3
please explain this to me

Answer (score 0):

If $x \propto y$ then $x = ky \Rightarrow y= x \frac{1}{k}$ which implies $y \propto x$

The variable isn't the same both ways.

So in other words, we have $y \propto x \Rightarrow y= c x$ where $c \neq k$ but rather $c= \frac{1}{k}$

Comment: please guide me further i can not understand your thought

Comment: If $x \propto y$ then we say by definition that $x=ky$ for some $k$. So we know now that the relationship between $x$ and $y$ is that $x=ky$. It can't be anything else, THAT is the relationship between the two. If you divide both sides by $k$ then you get $x \frac{1}{k}=y$ which doesn't change the equation, we still have the same thing. So now we have $\frac{1}{k}$ which is ANOTHER constant. Basically you can't use those proportionally statements and say $x=ky$ AND $y=kx$ for the same $k$ because it is not the same for both the equations. When you put the const. on the other side, it changes.